# How to open a database in Sql Browser which is encrypted by sqlCipher?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I apologize for the duplicate question if it is. I almost searched everywhere but couldn't find any solution.
see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxCYQ.png) and [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw6i5.png) To mention that I used the latest version of the SQLite browser on Windows.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: save the db unencrypted and down load it to a folder on your pc and that off the top of my hat this seems the most simple way to pull the db from  your test emulator use adb commands it is a pull cmd with <db location pathe space C:\folder name to copy to on the PC

Comment: Can you please explain the above comment in simple words.

Comment: Take a look at my code and let me know if you need more help I would like to see your code for using SqliteCypher if you have time

Answer (score 0):

Ok first you need to create the database as non encrypted
then open Android Studio and run the emulator with the code I will give you below
Now minimize every thing Emulator and Android Studio BUT BEFORE YOU DO THAT LOOK IN your logcat you will see the path to your DB Highlight and COPY that

Now find adb.exe folder it will be on C drive under where ever you installed AS. OR just do a search on C drive OK when you get to where that folder is HOLD DOWN the SHIFT KEY and RIGHT CLICK any where in the white SELECT "Open command Window here"

now in the command window type this
adb pull (do a right click and paste that path you coppied  C:\name of folder on your C Drive Best to create one and name it AASafe
bingo your data base is now on your PC in the folder AASafe HERE IS RHE CODE it is a method that needs to be called under onCreate

```
    // Is External Storage Avaiable if so use it and find the path for DBHelper
public void onAvail() {

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))) {

        File removable = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[1];
        THE_PATH = String.valueOf(removable) + "/Documents/";

        System.out.println("SD Card Path ==> " + THE_PATH);

    } else {// if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        THE_PATH = "";
        System.out.println("Internal Path ==> "+ THE_PATH);
    }
}
```